# How to get both sides of text to align

Tags: html, css

I have got the following main html page and I am trying to do a text-align: justfiy; justify: inter-words; but it doesn't seem to work. Is this mean to line both sides of the the text to make it look like a block? I am not sure if I explain this well enough but hope you guys understand what I am after:

```css
div.service1 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <h2>At PianoCourse101, your child can now learn how to play Classical music right from the comfort of your own home! It doesn't matter if your child has no music foundation because there are lessons suitable for beginners and advanced students! Based
      on the "Bastien Piano Basics series", your child will be able to learn the basic hand positions, posture, finger numbers and letter names!<br>There are four levels in the "Bastien Piano Basics" series, beginning with the primer level, which is suitable
      for beginners. Once your child has completed the primer level, your child will be able to progress to Level 1, follow by Level 2 and Level 3.<br>Currently, PianoCourse101 lessons are mainly for children but we also encourage if you are an adult
      and also wish to learn how to play the piano to join us! In due course, there will also be lessons for adults!</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <form class="signup-form" action="newsletters.php" method="POST">
    <div class="newsletters">
      <label>Enter your E-mail Address</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="index_form">
      <input type="text" name='email' placeholder="Enter E-mail Address">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Subscribe to PianoCourse101!</button>
    <br>

  </form>
</div>

<img class="snoopy" src="includes/pictures/snoopy.jpg" alt="snoopy playing the piano" />

<div class="services_heading">Services</div>
<div class="services">
  <div class="service1">
    <h1>Level 1</h1>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="signup.php">
        <p id="piano">&#127929;</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p>Purchase the Level 1 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $100<br>Yearly fee: $800</p>
  </div>

  <div class="service1">
    <h1>Level 2</h1>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="signup.php">
        <p id="violin">&#127931;</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p>Purchase the Level 2 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $150<br>Yearly fee: $1300</p>

  </div>
  <div class="service1">
    <h1>Level 3</h1>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="signup.php">
        <p id="sax">&#127927;</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p>Purchase the Level 3 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $200<br>Yearly fee: $1800</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using inter-word but it only lines up the left hand side...

Comment: I guess text-align justify is the closest but I think my problem is that there are less words on the right hand side and thus does not look justify

Comment: What part exactly doesn't seem to work? Seems to work as expected to me.

Comment: Can you try explaining it better?

Comment: I think it does work but the text might be too short and hence, the right hand side seems a bit odd.... but I think it is working

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it’s very difficult to discern what you exactly want.

If you wanted for prices to align with the right edge, you should use `flexbox` for parts of the layout.

If you would like to align text flush right while using `text-align: justify`, you need to **enable hyphenation** with the following `CSS` proprety:

```
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

div.service1 p,
dl {
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px
}

dl,
dl div {
  display: flex
}

dl {
  flex-direction: column
}

dl div {
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <h2>At PianoCourse101, your child can now learn how to play Classical music right from the comfort of your own home! It doesn't matter if your child has no music foundation because there are lessons suitable for beginners and advanced students! Based
      on the "Bastien Piano Basics series", your child will be able to learn the basic hand positions, posture, finger numbers and letter names!<br>There are four levels in the "Bastien Piano Basics" series, beginning with the primer level, which is suitable
      for beginners. Once your child has completed the primer level, your child will be able to progress to Level 1, follow by Level 2 and Level 3.<br>Currently, PianoCourse101 lessons are mainly for children but we also encourage if you are an adult
      and also wish to learn how to play the piano to join us! In due course, there will also be lessons for adults!</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=service1>
  <h1>Level 1</h1>
  <div class=image>
    <a href=signup.php>
      <h2 id=piano></h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <p>Purchase the Level 1 Subscription plan!<br><br> Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!
    <dl>
      <div>
        <dt>Monthly fee:
      <dd>$100
    </div>
    <div>
      <dt>Yearly fee:
      <dd>$800
    </div>
  </dl>
</div>
  
<div class=service1>
  <h1>Level 2</h1>
  <div class=image>
    <a href=signup.php>
      <h2 id=violin></h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <p>Purchase the Level 2 Subscription plan!<br><br>
    Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!
  <dl>
    <div>
      <dt>Monthly fee:
      <dd>$150
    </div>
    <div>
      <dt>Yearly fee:
      <dd>$1300
    </div>
  </dl>
</div>
    
<div class=service1>
  <h1>Level 3</h1>
  <div class=image>
    <a href=signup.php>
      <h2 id=sax></h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <p>Purchase the Level 3 Subscription plan!<br><br>
    Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!
  <dl>
    <div>
      <dt>Monthly fee:
      <dd>$200
    </div>
    <div>
      <dt>Yearly fee:
      <dd>$1800
    </div>
  </dl>
</div>
```